# Windows socket recv flags

Tags: c++, c, windows, sockets

I'm reading socket `recv()` documentation from msdn, and it is not clear to me what these flags do exactly:

```
int recv(
  _In_  SOCKET s,
  _Out_ char   *buf,
  _In_  int    len,
  _In_  int    flags //these
);
```

I peeked into [`winsock2.h`](https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/906386) and found the values of some flags  like: `MSG_OOB` and `MSG_PEEK`, but `MSG_WAITALL` is not defined there.

Can you please explain to me what each flag does and what is the value of it (int) ?

**Edit**: It seems that I was not clear in my question, but I did read the documentation section about the flag and I still do not understand the behavior of recv() with each flag, hence I'm asking for an explanation of each flag with an example if possible.

Comment: Flags are documented here (about halfway down): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx  If you search for "MSDN recv" (or another function) you will get the MS docs in the 1st hit.

Comment: As i mentioned i read that document but the description does not make sense to me. Maybe some examples will do

Comment: Maybe you should ask a specific question(s) the documentation seems clear to me, what is it specifically about each flag you do not understand?

Comment: The behavior for instance what is the behavior of recv when flags=0 or 4? Plus what are the values of each flag. I think the question is clear

Comment: Values of each flag are defined in `winsock2.h`. (if any are missing you need to update your SDK).  0 is no flags. 4 is `MSG_DONTROUTE` (probably) and is not documented as a valid flag for `recv` so expect an error and undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yeah , there are only like, three flags.  They are all clearly documented 'bitmask' boolean values that you can OR together as needed.  What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this MSDN article out on `recv()`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx

I've honestly not used any of these flags in all the networking work I've done, except for `MSG_PEEK` - I can't see why it'd come up in most situations these days.

You can look at the `WinSock2.h` header file and deduce the values from there:

```
#define MSG_OOB         0x1             /* process out-of-band data */
#define MSG_PEEK        0x2             /* peek at incoming message */
#define MSG_DONTROUTE   0x4             /* send without using routing tables */ 
#define MSG_WAITALL     0x8             /* do not complete until packet is */
```

Comment: grateful for this answer, but I'm lacking an explanation for each flag. for instance what if `MSG_PEEK=0x2` "peek at incoming msg" does that mean the buffer gets filled in while the transmission is happening? Why does code sample use flag 0x0? that's not even listed .. It's unclear even from the MSDN document

Comment: Peek just allows you to read data without taking it out of the queue. Useful if you want to delay when that happens.

Comment: @AK_: the documentation is quite clear on what each flag does. For instance, 0 means "no flags", and `MSG_PEEK` says: "*Peeks at the incoming data. The data is copied into the buffer, but is not removed from the input queue.*" What part of that is not clear to you? Data is received from the network and placed in the socket's input queue ready to be read by your code. When you then read from the input queue, `MSG_PEEK` copies the data into your buffer and leaves the data in the queue so the next `recv()` call can see it again (you are "peeking" at the data).

Comment: When i set flags=0x8 i get an error, why? It should be a blocking call and waits until the end of the transmission, right?